# Sharepoint; inheritance, full control problem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, inheritance

I'd like to give full control permission to one of my users to a **subsite**. I know that all subsites inheriting permissions default by its parent site.

However, I already changed many subsites' permissions from default to other permissions.

Is it possible to get out the several subsites' permissions to let my user work on those, that I don't give **full control** to my user's group, but **directly** to my user?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Breaking the inheritance is the first step. I understand you have already edited permissions. In the same window is a button to `Grant permissions`. Click it, add a user and check the box for `Full control`.